# Win32 Stack section base address

Tags: windows, stack, portable-executable, internals

I know that to find a text (code) section's base address one should look for the .text section virtual address (except if ASLR is enabled), but what about stack?

Is stack memory stored in the .data section along with the heap? If so I should look for .data section virtual address to know the stack base address

Comment: And to help other people: .data section contains global variables and NOT anything I wrote before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stack is not a section. A stack is dynamically allocated for each thread. (If it were a section, then you could have only one thread per process.)

Comment: so does the stack go with all the other heap data in the .data section per thread?

Comment: Read my answer again. The stack is not in any section at all.

Comment: Also +1 on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap